# Char array does not have null but String array does

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print a 2D array formed by a rectangle so a 4 by 4 would be something like this:

```
* * * *
*     *
*     *
* * * *
```

I realize that I can print that out through this code:

```java
int rows = 4;
int columns = 4;
char[][] rectangle = new char[rows][columns];
// fill array
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == rows - 1 || j == columns - 1) {
            rectangle[i][j] = '*';
        }
        System.out.print(rectangle[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But when I change the array type from char to String with the code below:

```java
int rows = 4;
int columns = 4;
String[][] rectangle = new String[rows][columns];
// fill array
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == rows - 1 || j == columns - 1) {
            rectangle[i][j] = "* ";
        }
        System.out.print(rectangle[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

It returns this:

```
* * * * 
* nullnull* 
* nullnull* 
* * * *
```

I know how to fix it when using the String array but I want to know why it has null values when it is a String but not char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well it is simply because `String` is Object, so it can have `null` value, and **null is default value for String**. On other side `char` is primitive type it just can not contain `null` value. Default value for char is `'\u0000'`

Comment: So does '\u0000' mean blank or " "?

Comment: it is blank character, actually it is https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm

Comment: ASCII code zero is called NULL and it has no visual representation. That you got spaces was luck, as it depends on where it is displayed. You might also get question marks, question marks in little boxes, little boxes containing the tiny text "NULL", little boxes containing the hex digits 0000, &c. 

Comment: Plus, what fallback is used by an application in case the character set doesn't have a glyph for NULL 

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of the Java core data types:

[image]

Note, that:

- `String` (or any object) has a default value - `null`
- `char` has a default value - `'\u0000'`, which, in turn, represents a [null character/terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), that is a non-printing [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII).